# 'Resource.String' Não contém uma definição para 'gcm_defaultSenderId' xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

Estou implementando o Push Notification em meu app, estava funcionando, mais agora da erro em duas variáveis não definidas no Resource na google_app_id e gcm_defaultSenderId. Quando tento adicioná-las manualmente no resource da certo de primeira mais na segunda ver que vou executar já me acusa o erro novamente (arquivo resource e substituído)

o que pode estar ocorrendo para elas não ficarem fixas em minha aplicação ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
   if (!GetString(Resource.String.google_app_id).Equals("000000000000000000000000000"))
                throw new System.Exception("Invalid Json file");

        Task.Run(() => {
            var instanceId = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;
            instanceId.DeleteInstanceId();
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("TAG", "{0} {1}", instanceId.Token, instanceId.GetToken(GetString(Resource.String.gcm_defaultSenderId), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope));
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre quando você tenta utilizar uma string que não foi criada no arquivo Strings.xml.

Dentro da raiz do seu projeto, entre na pasta Resources/values e abra o arquivo Strings.xml. Caso não tenha esse arquivo, crie um novo exatamente com esse nome "Strings" do tipo XML.

A estrutura dele é a seguinte (já com as strings que você precisa):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId">12345</string>
  <string name="google_app_id">12345</string>
</resources>
```

Caso você tenha mais de um arquivo Strings.xml, que pode acontecer no caso de você estar utilizando suporte a multi-linguagem, adicione as duas strings em todos os arquivos Strings.xml para evitar possíveis erros.

Não esqueça de dar *Rebuild* no projeto após modificar esses arquivos.